# Inequality and fixed numbers

Tags: inequality

I have the following inequality that seems like true but I just can't prove it
$$\left|\frac{a}{b}\right| + \left|\frac{b}{a}\right| \ge 2$$
It looks right (and I can't find an example that prove it wrong) but how can the one mathematically prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love this inequality

> $$\left\lvert\frac ab\right\rvert+\left\lvert\frac ba\right\rvert\ge2$$

$$\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2\ge0$$

$$x^2-2+\frac{1}{x^2}\ge0$$

$$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\ge2$$

Now put $$\left\lvert\frac ab\right\rvert=x^2$$

Or use **AM-GM**

$$\frac{\left\lvert\frac ab\right\rvert+\left\lvert\frac ba\right\rvert}{2}\ge\sqrt{\left\lvert\frac ab\right\rvert\cdot\left\lvert\frac ba\right\rvert}=\sqrt{\frac{ab}{ab}}=1$$

$$\left\lvert\frac ab\right\rvert+\left\lvert\frac ba\right\rvert\ge2$$

Comment: wow thanks how did you think about it?

Answer (score 2):

The inequality is equivalent to
$$
|a^2|+|b^2|\ge 2|a|\,|b|
$$
(for $a\ne0$ and $b\ne0$). Set $x=|a|$ and $y=|b|$, to turn it into the easier
$$
x^2+y^2\ge 2xy
$$
that you should be able to manage.